# Video is not shared to facebook account

Tags: html, facebook

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="appsid" /> 
<meta property="og:url"  content="http://103.231.125.106/nesos/fblink.jsp" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/151014150717SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'}}" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/151014150717SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'}}" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="300" />
```

*Video not playing in same page of facebook*

Comment: Should be https:// and not https//

Comment: @WizKid, still not working dude

Comment: So what is the URL to your site?

Comment: That is a local IP. How would Facebook be able to scrape that one?

Comment: @WizKid,dude my video shared perfectly to facebook account,but that video is not playing in same facebook page,when i clicked shared video link then it open new pAGE where my video start playing but i want play video in facebook page not in new page

Comment: Which I would guess is because Facebook can't scrape your url

Comment: @WizKid,dude any required config.xml file for sharing video?

Comment: If Facebook can't reach your server how would that matter?

Comment: @WizKid, sir i have given live ip addess ,still it not working ,please help me

Comment: @WizKid,video is not playing in facebook page ,but it play in new window,when i clicked  on shared link

Comment: So what is the real url?

Comment: @WizKid,http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/150930171515SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4

Comment: @WizKid, Full Url Including FLOW PLAYER--http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/150930171515SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'

Comment: What is the URL to the page that contains OG-tags?

Comment: @WizKid---<meta property="og:video" content="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'http://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/150930171515SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'}}" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf?config={'clip':{'url':'https://103.231.125.106/nesos/videoappsuser/150930171515SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4'}}" />

Comment: @WizKid, sir Please check 2nd box ,which i have posted today

Comment: That is not the URL to the page that contains OG-tags

Comment: You need to answer people's questions accurately if you want to get help, @naveen maurya.
What @WizKid asked is the URL for the document that contains the OpenGraph `<meta>` tags.

Comment: @WizKid,hi dude sorry i am too late please help me as you said placed the url i have placed url tag still video not playing in same page , check below code

Comment: @WizKid, check upadated post ,i hope u will help me

Comment: No it doesn't help. What is the URL to the page that contains those tags

Comment: @WizKid,please help me

Comment: @WizKid,dude u r my last hope